# sharing a class between two wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to share the following class between at least two wpf windows:

```
namespace WPF
{
    class dd_internals  
    {
        public int current_process_index;

        public class process_class
        {
           public string process_name;
           public List<string> parm_list;
           public List<string> var_list;
           public List<string> statements;
       }

       public List<process_class> process_list = new List<process_class>();
   }
}
```

How would I share a single instance of this class between multiple windows?

Ok code showing `dd_internals` being passed into the constructor of `window1`, but not usable directly in a member function of `window1`.

```
namespace posting2
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public void Member()
        {
            int y = Data.current_process_index;
            // Error: the name 'Data' does not exist in the current context
        }

        public Window1(dd_internals data)
        {
            int x = data.current_process_index;
            // ok, it works here.

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info to really tell, but possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by to “share a single instance”. An example of what good you think that will do will be helpful.

Comment: share a single instance: meaning there is one class x and both windows update it and the updates show up anywhere it accessed.  In c++ one module might define class x, and all others would access class *ref where ref=&x.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options, for example:

1. As I  can guess one window can open another window, so you can just pass an instance of this object to the second window before opening it.
2. You can store it in Application.Properties

   Application.Current.Properties["Key"] = myobject;
3. The best option for bigger application is to use some dependency container (there are many implementations of it) and store shared object in such a container
4. I really don't like the singleton pattern because it is not actually a pattern, but you can use it too.

Comment: There is difference in forcing only 1 instance available and creating&using only 1 instance. In the latter case your approach works, but if it is mandatory that only one instance is ever created during application lifecycle, then singleton is the way to go. The instance can be passed as a parameter or assigned to application resources.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dd = new dd_internals();
var window1 = new YourWindow(dd);
var window2 = new YourWindow(dd);
```

Any change you make to `dd` will be available in all window instances. If you need to handle things like multithreading, or having `dd` call something when something is changed, you need to add that to your question.

Your edit is syntactically invalid; C# is case-sensitive so `Data` and `data` are two different identifiers, one of which is not declared. I'm guessing you want something like:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private readonly dd_internals myDd;

    public void Member()
    {
        int y = myDd.current_process_index;
    }

    public Window1(dd_internals data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myDd = data;
    }
}
```

In your real project please use better names than “data”, “Window1” et al. Those names don't mean anything; in a short example they are useful but they quickly make a real program incomprehensible.

Comment: The issue I have here dd is only seen in say window1 constructor...to make it available to any member function of window1 you need something like local_dd=dd and make local_dd something in window1.  Which I can do...but then on windows1 exit you have to copy it dd=local_dd...seems messy.

Comment: You have to create `dd` outside the window constructor and pass it in. You don't need to copy anything. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34440333/edit) your post to show your code as I don't understand what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to make the class public or internal before sharing it anywhere.

Comment: That is only necessary if you want the class to be visible to other *assemblies*.

Comment: Agreed. If in the same assembly then should it not at least be 'internal'. The class dd_internals as shown is 'private' by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can make class singleton

```
 public  class dd_internals
    {
        private static dd_internals instance;
        public static dd_internals singleInstance;

        private dd_internals() { }

        public static dd_internals Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new dd_internals();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public int current_process_index;
        public class process_class
        {
            public string process_name;
            public List<string> parm_list;
            public List<string> var_list;
            public List<string> statements;
        }
        public List<process_class> process_list = new List<process_class>();
    }
```